# How to copy a file from HDFS to a Windows machine?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I want to copy a .csv file from our Hadoop cluster in my local Desktop, so I can edit the file and upload back (replace).
I tried:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /c_transaction_label.csv C:/Users/E_SJIRAK/Desktop
```

which yielded:

> copyToLocal: '/Users/E_SJIRAK/Desktop': No such file or directory:
> file:////Users/E_SJIRAK/Desktop

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH'd into the Hadoop cluster, then you cannot `copyToLocal` into Windows.

You need a 2 step process. Download from HDFS to the Linux environment. Then use SFTP (WinSCP, Filezilla, etc) or Putty `scp` command from Windows host to get files into your Windows machine.

Otherwise, you need to setup `hadoop` CLI command on Windows itself.